# Validate jquery selector syntax using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex expression in javascript to validate whether a string is a valid jquery selector. This is strictly educational and not a particular requirement in any project of mine

*Pattern*

`/^(\$|Jquery)\(('|")[\.|#]?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9!]*('|")\)$/gi`

It works fine for below tests

`$("#id")//true`

`$('.class')//true`

`jquery('.class')//true`

`jquery('div')//true`

My problem is that the test on `$('#id")` also returns true i.e, using mixing single and double quote in js in invalid. How to restrict this. Can we have conditional regex?

```js
const pattern = /^(\$|Jquery)\(('|")[\.|#]?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9!]*('|")\)$/gi;

[
`$("#id")`, //true
`$('.class')`, //true
`jquery('.class')`, //true
`jquery('div')`, //true
].forEach(str => console.log(pattern.test(str)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can capture the first quote or doublequote in a group, and require that same group (the same quote or doublequote) at the end, using a backreference:

```js
const re = /^(?:\$|Jquery)\((['"])[\.#]?[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9!]*\1\)$/gi;
console.log(re.test(`$("#id")`))
console.log(re.test(`$('#id")`))
console.log(re.test(`$("#id')`))
console.log(re.test(`$('#id')`))
```

There are also a couple other things to fix:

```
/^\$|Jquery...
```

meant that *any* string starting with `$` would fulfill the regex. Enclose it in a group instead.

Single quote `'` doesn't need escaping - best to remove the backslash.

Rather than

```
[\.|#]?
```

if you want to *possibly* match `.` or `#` (and not a pipe), use `[\.#]?` instead

Comment: so the `\1` does the trick which matches with the 1st capturing group

Comment: wt does `?:` do?

Comment: It makes the group a non-capturing group - this way, the first captured group is the quotes, allowing for `\1` later. (Could have just as easily used a standard first group instead and then backreferenced using `\2`)